# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $B$, prove that $\lambda^4$ is an eigenvalue of $B^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is what I have so far:

Let $\lambda$  be an eigenvalue of $B, Bv = \lambda v$.
$B(Bv) = B(\lambda v)$.

\begin{align*}
B^2v &= \lambda Bv= \lambda \lambda v= \lambda^2v\\
B^3v &= \lambda \lambda Bv = \lambda \lambda \lambda v= \lambda^3v\\
B^4v &= \lambda \lambda \lambda Bv = \lambda \lambda \lambda \lambda v= \lambda^4
\end{align*}

Thus, $\lambda^4$ is an eigenvalue of $B^4$.

Is this correct? If so is there anything else I should add?

Comment: It's correct; no you don't have to add anything else.

Comment: That's correct. In general, if $p$ is a polynomial and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$, $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.

Comment: Is it necessary to mention that v ≠ 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely correct. Well done!

One little remark: you could mention the following:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $B$ and $v$ be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ (you didn't say that $v$ was an eigenvector, although this is obvious)

Also, it is not necessary to mention that $v\neq 0$ as an eigenvector is not equal to zero by defintion.

Comment: Is there any significance of mentioning that v is an eigenvector to λ?

Comment: @AmR The equation $Bv=\lambda v$ only holds for an eigenvector of $\lambda$, but as you’ve written the proof, $v$ could be *any* vector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct and there is nothing more that should be added. In addition, exactly what Pedro Tamaroff♦ said in the comments section, in general, if $p$ is a polynomial and $λ$ an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$, then $p(λ)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your proof for this question is correct! This would be similar for any value of $n$: $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $B^n$.